# Is there a way to add a char or tab on the beginning of each line on a String (StringBuilder)?

Tags: java

I need to print an object, and this objects contains other objects inside. The desired output is a multilevel print like this:

```
[
    [
      [ 
      ]
    ]
]
```

I could change the toString methods from the internal classes, but I would like to avoid that, and only  thought the toString method in my class.

Any thoughts?

Solution:

`
    public String toString() {

```
    StringBuilder usina = new StringBuilder();

    usina.append("Usina: [\n\t");

    for (Turbina turbina : turbinas)
        usina.append(turbina.toString().replace("\n", "\n\t"));

    usina.append(populacao.toString().replace("\n", "\n\t"));

    usina.append("]\n").deleteCharAt(usina.lastIndexOf("\t"));
    return usina.toString();

}
```

`

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for the edit, I was just trying to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using an external library, you can use a json library to easily get pretty printed JSON string of your objects.

For example with Gson:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(yourObject);
```

If you plan to override `toString()`, you can use `\t` for tabs and `\n` for line breaks.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to avoid adding libraries, or classes in general here. That is why I thought that StringBuilder would be a way out of this issue. Maybe with regular expressions - though, I have never used before in Java.

Comment: So simple...  Thanks...
Although some finding and removing was necessary, this solved my issue. I replaced with replace() =) hahaha

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should override `toString` like this

```
public String toString() {
  return toStringWithPrefix("")
}
```

and then recursively delegate to your nested objects in the `toStringWithPrefix(..)`  method like this

```
String toStringWithPrefix(String prefix) {
  String result = "["
  for(AnObject obj : internalObjects) {
     result += obj.toStringWithPrefix(prefix + "\t") + ",\n";
  }
  return result + "]"
}
```

Offcourse you can use a `StringBuilder` or a `StringBuffer` if you want to build the String representation of larger object graphs. In this case you might consider to replace the recursion with a stack and a while loop, to avoid stackoverflows.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, but I would like to touch as minimum as possible. That would work... but the solution above seems more what was necessary (less effects on the class and no adding methods - this was kind what I was asked to do as a requirement). Thanks any way.

Comment: The effect on the public interface of the class is minimal in the sense that it doesn't add any visible methods.

Comment: Hi, I agreed (Sorry for the late answer), but there is a huge chain of classes involved and some of them we dont have access to. If it was just three or four levels...so we deceided to change just the final class, and regular expressions with replace() or replaceAll in Matcher was the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that class you want to print looks similar to this:

```
class A
{
    int primitive;
    Object object;
    Object[] array;
    // ...
}
```

2 ideas:

1. Override `toString()` in `A`. `\n` is a new line (you can use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get new line character), `\t` is a tabulator.

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString()
   {
       final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[\n");
       sb.append('\t\n');
       sb.append(primitive);
       sb.append('\t\n');
       sb.append(object.toString());
       sb.append('\t\n');
       sb.append(Arrays.toString(array));
       // ... 
       sb.append(']');     
       return sb.toString();
   }
   ```

   It assumes that `object` also provides correct `toString()` implementation.
2. Like before, but use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html) to get all the members instead of hard-coding them.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem here is that the objects have lots of new line too, so I cant use append.

Answer (score 0):

Final result:

`
@Override
    public String toString() {

```
    StringBuilder outter = new StringBuilder();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)(^)"); //Line begin: multiline mode
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inners.toString());

    outter.append("[\n");

    outter.append(matcher.replaceAll("\t"));

    outter.append("]\n");


    return outter.toString();

}
```

`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE

Comment: inners has several further levels.